# Split file having Integers and string into strings only

Tags: java, string, delimiter, trie

i have the file which has data stored as       " Integer-> \t(tab)-> String ->couple of space-> ".

Am I doing Wrong?

What I am doing is.

```
    Trie t = new Trie();
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "H:\\100kfound.txt"));

    String line;
    String[] s = null;
    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {

        s = line.split("\t");

    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(s[i]);
        if (!(s[i].matches("\\d+"))) {

            t.addWord(s[i]);
            System.out.println(s[i]);
        }
    }
```

What I can see by debugging it is going properly till while loop but in for loop it just stores two strings and prints the same.

Comment: You know that you throw away all lines but the last one with this code?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to and a ^[0-9]+$ for the expressions so you just get complete integers.  Without the ^ and $ you could be matching other characters like tt55gh would match.

```
if (!(s[i].matches("^[0-9]+$"))) {
}
```

Per the comment above you need to move the for loop inside the while loop.

```
while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {

    s = line.split("\t");

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Value "+i+": "+s[i]);
        if (!(s[i].matches("^[0-9]+$"))) {
            t.addWord(s[i]);
            System.out.println("Integer "+i+": "+s[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No relief Joe. I have huge File more than 10000 strings.does it impact it.?